# How to set error message if user key in wrong input in EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, validation, message

I've an application where there are EditText boxes. I've set validatin for the boxes of what inout the user should key in. But I want to set error message if he keys in wrong input which I'm not sure how to do that.

These are the validation codes for the edittext

```
EditText txtDislikes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDislikes);
        txtDislikes.setHint("e.g. Skating, Photography separate by comma");
        txtDislikes.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {

                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start,
                            int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
                    {
                        if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[a-z A-Z -]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                }
            });
```

I've tried to type in like `source.setError("ONLY LETTERS ARE ALLOWED");` in

```
if(source.equals(""))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            source.setError("ONLY LETTERS ARE ALLOWED");
                        }
                        if(source.toString().matches("[a-z A-Z -]+"))
                        {
                            return source;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            source.setError("ONLY LETTERS ARE ALLOWED");
                        }
                        return "";
```

But I've got error says "The method setError(String) is undefined for the type CharSequence". Not sure what that means.

Plus, I couldn't find any good examples for this. Any help or examples provided will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog)

Comment: there is no setError() method for CharSequence. You should do `txtDislikes.setError()` not `source.setError()`

Comment: @Aprian you should post it as an answer

Comment: @nandeesh was not sure if that is an answer, will post it now.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `setError()` method for type `CharSequence`.

Refer to [TextView.setError()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), you should `setError()` on your `txtDislikes` instead of `source`.